# Google Таблицы: вывести часть таблицы #1 в таблицу #2

Tags: google-spreadsheet

У меня есть две обновляемых Google Таблицы. В Таблице №1 ведутся основные работы по ручному заполнению данных. В Таблице №2 мне нужно вывести часть столбцов из Таблицы №1, например столбцы A2:D500. Решил данную задачу с помощью IMPORTRANGE:
`=IMPORTRANGE("1Wrh_5DCrxlQ-B4fECi64VMeFAvuqyEilLXo1Xqmc"; "Закупка!A2:D500")`

В таблице №2 в ручную дополняют вывод из Таб.№1, но в других колонках: E, F, G

В этой всей конструкции есть большая проблема, когда в Таб.№1 удаляют любую строку, в Таб.№2 она так же удаляется, но заполненные данные в колонках E, F, G, съезжают и уже не соответствуют изначальным строкам выведенным из таб.1, как это было при их заполнении.

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ вывести информацию из одной таблицы в другую, но с привязкой к строке, что бы если в таб.1 удаляются или меняются строки местами, в таб.2 данные так же менялись, но целиком с веденными данными в строке?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Да, вы должны в Таблице 2 иметь отдельную колонку, в которую должны **вручную** вводить данные из Таблицы 1, это может быть какая-то колонка с уникальными значениями. Далее, в Таблице 2, после этого значения в строке вы вводите нужные вам данные, типа `E, F, G`.

Отлично, теперь на листе с `IMPORTRANGE` в Таблице 2 соедините выводы через уникальную колонку и `VLOOKUP`.

Простой пример https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dQhEllKGmfyDIdEkRtCNUiNYs0sC8dlN1Cw_ugmMeKI/edit?usp=sharing

Теперь, если данные даже будут удалены из Таблицы 1, часть введенных данных в Таблице 2 останется как есть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Идея отличная, теперь нужен скрипт который будет автоматом генерировать ключ в таб.1, при создании новой строки, и переносить этот сгенерированный ключ в таб.2

Comment: Если такой уникальной колнки нет, вы можете попробовать сгененрировать что-то простое типа `=ARRAYFORMULA(A:A&B:B&C:C)`. Главное, чтобы `A`, `B` и `C` были неизменяемы для Таблицы 1